# How to use d3.js convex hull?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization

I recently asked a question on here, but wanted to simplify it perhaps to get a response..

can anyone advise on using d3.geom.hull to draw shapes around a series of points?

I have data grouped into 3, and I would like to create a "hull" encompasing each group. I have managed to do it for one, but have trouble to do it for all 3.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to change an existing question, please do that instead of asking a new one.

Comment: Isn't the hull that encompasses each group the same as the hull for the data when it is not grouped?  Can't you just combine all of the data points and get the hull for that?